# transform: translate() behaves incorrect in safari

Tags: html, css

I am using transform: translate(%here); to animate a circular transition. basically I have 3 items in a row, and I shift the first and third. The code works fine, except in safari and mobile devices. In safari, the transform: translate(%here) value seem to be a) incorrect and the animation goes wild, b) the animation doesn't even start until you switch tabs for example. This is the code and [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRGryx)

```
HTML
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="anim.css">
    </head>

    <body>

                <div class="svg-wrapper">
                  <div class="svg-container second">

                <object class="tape tape-1 center"  width="15%" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/circles3.svg"></object>
                <object class="tape tape-2 center"  width="15%" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/circles3.svg"></object>
                <object class="tape tape-3 center"  width="15%" type="image/svg+xml" data="http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/newstuff/circles3.svg"></object>

                  </div>
              </div>

    </body>
</html>

CSS:

.tape-1.center{
    left:12%;
    width:15%;
       -webkit-animation: slide-down 3.9s ease;
    -moz-animation: slide-down 3.9s ease;
    -o-animation: slide-down 3.9s ease;
    animation: slide-down 3.9s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
.tape-2.center{

    /*-webkit-animation: slide-in-2 3.9s ease;*/
    /*animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    transform: translateX(284%);
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
}
.tape-3.center{
    left:73.3366%;
    width:15%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: slide-up 3.9s ease;
    -moz-animation: slide-up 3.9s ease;
    -o-animation: slide-up 3.9s ease;
    animation: slide-up 3.9s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
    -o-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);


  }
  33.3% {
    /*transform: translateY(105%);*/
    -webkit-transform: translateY(105%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(105%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(105%);
    -o-transform: translateY(105%);
    transform: translateY(105%);
  }
  66.6%{

        /*transform: translateX(490%);
        transform: translateY(105%);*/
        /*transform: translate(410.9%,105%);*/

    -webkit-transform: translate(410.9%,105%);
    -moz-transform: translate(410.9%,105%);
    -ms-transform: translate(410.9%,105%);
    -o-transform: translate(410.9%,105%);
    transform: translate(410.9%,105%);

    }
  100% {

    /*transform: translate(410.9%,0%);*/

    -webkit-transform: translate(410.9%,0%);
    -moz-transform: translate(410.9%,0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(410.9%,0%);
    -o-transform: translate(410.9%,0%);
    transform: translate(410.9%,0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-up {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0%,0%);
  }
  33.3% {
    transform: translateY(-105%);

  }
  66.6%{
        transform: translate(-410.7%,-105%);
    }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-410.7%,0%);
  }
}

/*CONTAINER DATA*/
.svg-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  /* whatever width you want */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.svg-wrapper:after {
  padding-top: 80.7%;
  /* 16:9 ratio */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
.svg-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* fill parent */
  background-color: red;
  /* let's see it! */
  color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: tape-1
}

.tape{
    position: absolute;
    top:34.5%;  

}
```

Just copy paste it and replace                     `data="assets/piece.svg"`
 with some svg file on your file system.

I am not sure what could be the reason for this behaviour. If i switch tabs between and come back to this code, the animation is working. If I lock the phone and undlock it, the animation magically starts working. Any ideas what have I missed?

Comment: **Just copy paste it and replace...** Instead, why don't you just make a jsfiddle, or even better, embed this into a snippet within your question?

Comment: I don't know what is the reason for incorrect behaviour. It could be the use of <object class="tape tape-3 center" width="15%" type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/piece.svg"></object>. referencing external svg files is somewhat different approach than local. I hope that jutifies my decision. But you are correct, lets eliminate some possibilities.

Comment: My bad, referencing external source is exactly the same.